# Formatting date and time using Moment with React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm new into coding and I'm trying to format date as `DD/MM/YYYY` and time as `HH:MM` using React Moment. I tried many methods with no success. It would be great if anyone could help me with this issue, as I'm still learning the basics.

How am I supposed to format `{props.date}` and `{props.time}` to make it more user-friendly?

Here's the code that I have:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import CreatedAtShow from "./CreatedAtShow";
import { Opportunities } from "../requests";
import { OpportunityShowPage } from "./OpportunityShowPage";
import moment from "react-moment";

function OpportunityDetails(props) {
  return (
        <div>
              <h2>
                  Opportunity: <br />
                  {props.title}
              </h2>
              <p></p>
              <h3>
                  Description: <br />
                  {props.description}
              </h3>
              
              <p>Tag:{props.tags}</p>
              <p>Date:{props.date}</p>
              <p>Time: {props.time}</p>
              <p>Where: {props.where}</p>
              <p>Contact information: {props.contact}</p>
              <p><CreatedAtShow created_at={props.created_at} /></p>    
  
              <button className="ui button"
                onClick={() => {
                    props.editOpportunity(props.id);
                }}
                > 
                Edit 
              </button>

              <button className="ui button"
              
                  onClick={() => props.deleteOpportunity(props.id)
                    // props.deleteOpportunity(props.id);
                  }> 
                  Delete 
              </button>
        </div>
  );
}

export default OpportunityDetails;
```

Comment: Hi, can you please provide some inputs and desired outputs for date

Comment: What do they look like now? Can you post what the current format of `props.date` and `props.time` are? Moment.js has a `.parse` and a `.format` function, have you used those before?

Comment: Right now the formats are: Date:2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z and Time: 2020-06-24T15:00:00.000Z

Answer (score 1):

you can use momement js `format` function like this to get the desired part from date. If you can provide me some sample inputs and desired outputs then i can give you the exact answer. If you want to use with official moment.js npm then use below code.

If you want to get date and time from existing date then you can follow this:

```
<p>Date:{moment(props.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY"}</p>
<p>Time:{moment(props.time).format("HH:MM")}</p>
```

If you want today's or system date to be displayed then you can use:

```
<p>Date:{moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY"}</p>
<p>Time:{moment().format("HH:MM")}</p>
```

If you want to use react-moment then you can try this:

```
<p>Date:<Moment format="DD/MM/YYYY">{props.date}</Moment></p>
<p>Time:<Moment format="HH:MM">{props.time}</Moment></p>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Comment: i see you are using react-moment not official moment.js npm. If you want you can install moment using `npm install moment` then just `import moment from "moment"` in your project and try.

Comment: if you want to use react-moment then you can get the code from above. The other thing you have to change is the import like `import Moment from "react-moment"`